# Apache </Location> Errors

Tags: apache-2.2

I am having real trouble with this installation - Basically this is the erro that I am getting:

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 234 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 10 of /etc/apache2/conf.d/amberdms-bs.conf: Expected </Location\xc2\xa0/billing_system> but saw </Location>
```

and this is the code that is being used in that modules file:

```
# 
# Amberdms Billing System is an open source accounting, service billing and time keeping web application. 
# 
Alias /billing_system /usr/share/amberdms/billing_system 
<Location /billing_system> 
Order deny,allow 
Allow from all 
AllowOverride all 
</Location>
```

Please help me! I need this software to be installed, but this error has stumped me.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like the `<Location>` directive has a non-breaking space instead of a normal breaking space. Remove the space and retype it.

Comment: thank you so much, can't believe I fell for that! Cheers for the quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

You need a closing  tag for starters, and i'd also put the path in double quotes:

```
<Location "/billing_system">
  Order deny, allow
  Allow from all
  AllowOverride all
</Location>
```